# How to re-create the selection of approvers and order ( OOTB Approval workflow ) on a custom approval workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

How can I make the functionality of the OOTB Approval workflow  where they can select the approvers and order ( Serial or parallel ) on a  custom form?

I would need to let the users select their own approvers on the fly like the OOTB .Is this possible?

Like the one below:
[image: re-create the selection of approvers and order ( OOTB Approval workflow )]